# Laravel backend not saving to database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, http

I'm uploading files using laravel as backend API REST. When I upload a file in the frontend, it sends a 200 OK status code in the response, but doesn't save it to the database. Something weird that I see it's that in the response the data comes empty, and the array of the files comes in the config section of the response.
[image: 200 ok response]

This is the controller that handles this situation

```
 public function makeFile(Request $request)
    {
        $fileArray = [];
    if (isset($request->files) && is_array($request->files)) {
        foreach ($request->files as $key => $fileEntity) {
            $file= new File();
            $file->file=$fileEntity['file'];
            $file->shipment_id=$fileEntity['shipment_id'];
            $file->user_id=$fileEntity['user_id'];
            $file->date=date('Y,m,d,G,i,s');
            $file->fileName=$fileEntity['fileName'];
            $file->fileType=$fileEntity['fileType'];
            $file->status=$fileEntity['status'];
            $file->save();

            $fileArray[] = $file;
        }
    }
    return response()->json($fileArray);
    }
```

This is my form

```
<uib-tab index="1" heading="Files">
                        <div class="row">
                        <label>Add File</label>
                            <ul class="shipment__files">
                                <li class="col-xs-12 col-md-6" ng-repeat="file in shipment.shipmentObject.files">
                                    <a href="#"><img ng-src="{{ file.iconURL }}" width="60"></a>
                                    <div class="filename"><a href="#">{{ file.fileName }}</a></div>
                                    <div class="date">{{ file.date }}</div>
                                    <div class="uploader">{{ file.user_id }}</div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- <form>
                        <input type="file" name="" ng-model="shipment.shipmentObject.file">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="shipment.makeFile(shipmentObject.file)" >Upload File</button>

                        <div>aa {{ newFile }}</div>
                        </form> -->
                        <div>
                          <input data-my-Directive type="file" name="file" ng-model="shipment.shipmentObject.file">
                          <p>
                            post request with this data:
                          </p>
                          <pre ng-repeat="(key, value) in fileLog">
                            {{key}} {{ value }}
                          </pre>
                        </div>

                    </uib-tab>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're getting an empty response because your conditional statement isn't matching, so you're just returning that empty `$fileArray` you created:

```
if (isset($request->files) && is_array($request->files))
```

The correct way to check if there are files is to go:

```
if($request->hasFile('file'))
```

Everything you need to know about this is available in the official documentation here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#files

Comment: Im not getting an empty response, the response is 200 OK but its not saving it into the database. @giollianosulit

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer correctly. You're getting 200 because **youre returning an empty array**. The code in your if statement will never run. Check my solution above.

Comment: I understand, I put it like you mentioned. if($request->hasFile('file')) and added an dd("here") to debugg it, and I try it with postman. No "here" were printed. But when I change the if statment for this: if($request->files){ the dd"here" are printed. so that means the if statment its correctly. when i put the dd"here" inside the foreach, postman returns a "[]"... why is that? @giollianosulit

Comment: What is your file <input> named? I posted the answer assuming you had one named, **file**

Comment: yas, its named file
<input type="file" name="file" ng-model="shipment.shipmentObject.file">
@giollianosulit

Comment: Did you remove the other check for isset? Can you post the full solution above

Comment: Yes I removed it like you suggest, I got no solution, im still playing with the controllers, both in frontend angularjs and in the backedn with laravel. @giollianosulit

Comment: Actually, not sure why I didn't see this at the start. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload -  is that how you're posting your Form? I think you'd need FormData

Comment: well, that answer doesn't work for me, because im not using ajax or jquery... @giollianosulit

Comment: Can you add your full form page to the initial question and also controller. That will help

Comment: I make a better question for this, based on what you ask me for. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494929/uploading-file-from-angular-controller-to-laravel-api) @giollianosulit

Comment: And have you got the JS that posts the form ?